# How to make screenshot of select option element expanded?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, firefox-extensions

Is a way to make webpage screenshot by chrome/firefox extension on expanded `<select/> / <option/>` ? I'm using `Awesome Screenshot`, but shortcuts doesn't work in that situation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [FireShot firefox plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fireshot/) using Capture browser window feature.

> [FireShot](https://getfireshot.com/) helps you capture web page screenshots, perform quick edits,
>   add text annotations, and save the captures as a PDF or image file,
>   send to e-mail, print or copy to clipboard, export, share on the WWW
>   or upload to FTP.
>
> Capture browser window feature also known as browsershot implemented
>   in FireShot Pro.

You want something what can be done with Print Screen and Paint but for browser only? [Got it now](https://getfireshot.com/buy.php) for only $39.95 . No monthly fee, no annual fee and no other hidden costs!

You can give a [try to the full Pro Version with a switch](https://getfireshot.com/using.php#activating) and use it for absolutely free in a 30 day period.

[image]